# QGIS Cloud: WFS error Download of capabilities failed: Protocol "" is unknown

Tags: qgis, wfs, cloud-gis

I published a map with several vector layers from QGIS 3.4 to QGIS Cloud (with the plugin). I activated WFS in the project properties. However, when I try to connect to WFS in QGIS desktop, the connection is established and I see the layers in the browser panel. But when I try to add them to the layers panel, I get an error message: `Download of capabilities failed: Protocol "" is unknown"`.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Hitting the same error on my local trying to run QGIS server in docker and connecting to it with QGIS desktop,

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue: connection established, layer displayed in browser panel, WFS features accessible through web browser.

After franticly trying everything it turned out that setting the WFS connection version to 1.0 in the QGIS desktop client worked.